# Is the 4 Corners Monument wrong, or is Google Maps wrong?

Tags: usa, landmarks, geography

This is around trying to travel to a specific point.  People do this for the tropics, for the Greenwich Meridian, the equator and more.

The 4 Corners monument is meant to be on the corner of Colorado, Utah, Arizona and New Mexico.

However, [Google Maps](https://www.google.com/maps/place/36%C2%B059%2756.3%22N+109%C2%B002%2742.7%22W/@37.0007062,-109.0457242,637m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0xbc7088eb5b1601e8!8m2!3d36.998979!4d-109.045186?hl=en) has border lines for the state visible, that do NOT properly intersect with the monument, missing the center.

So if I wanted to stand on the actual corner and know at the time that I was, which is correct?

[image]

Comment: Just for clarification, looking at the cars for scale, there is a discrepancy of some 5 to 10 meters that you are trying to resolve?

Comment: OSM doesn't have this discrepancy, which lends credence to the idea this is something to do with Google Maps.

Comment: @quarague this isn't the only place this happens. For the travel nerds who like to go to 'the spot', it's petty but annoying.  Went to equator monument in Ecuador and there were like 3 official places, and my phone's GPS claimed something else!

Comment: I use satellite imagery provided by Google (eg Landsat) quite a lot for work. Most of the time it's pretty accurate but can be a few metres off occasionally. This looks like one of those occasions. Just some bad georeferencing or a bad capture. Incidentally, I'm georeferencing an area manually at the moment (which is time-consuming) because the camera alignment and altitude data that was captured at the same time as the image was taken was off, so I'm having to rotate the image and distort it to get it to match the actual points on Earth.

Comment: Related Ecuador post: https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/4150/101

Comment: I'd figure that the boundaries GE uses might be at least to some extent generalized, hence not always perfectly aligned with the actual borders. Though in this case it would be weird, since the borders are straight lines.

Comment: I believe there are two issues here: (1) georegistration of satellite imagery such as Google Earth's and Google Maps's is a really hard problem.  Google seems to do a very good job, but doing a *perfect* job of georegistering aerial photograms is almost impossible (because photographs are flat, and the Earth surely isn't). (2) Google's databases of state, county, and city boundaries are, in my experience, *not* too good.  I've overlaid USGS topo maps onto Google Earth and confirmed that the boundary lines Google has are significantly off.

Comment: In summary, the state boundaries Google has don't define Four Corners at all. The photographic evidence of the monument is better, but still not perfect — i.e., not necessarily exactly what you'd get if in the real world you put a survey-grade GPS receiver at the monument's center.

Comment: The "error" seems to be the same amount as the drawn 597 overshoots the real road visible on the image. And that seems to be common for Google maps, overlay of roads, waterways, and other features over areal images are often "off" by a few meters.

Comment: A side note: We visited 4 Corners last summer. Well, we got close... It was shut down for the Great Fear. I'd suggest you do some research to see if they've reopened before you drive a fair bit out of your way only to be disappointed. BTW- as we were backing out of the entry way, 2 other cars were pulling in, so it wasn't well advertised. It may still not be well advertised.

Comment: @FreeMan what on earth is the "great fear"? If you're referring to covid, please try to be sensitive. I know people who've died from it.

Comment: @SteveSummit It could also be exactly what you would get.  I would think they used professional survey grade techniques and equipment to place the monument (though I don't know that for a fact).

Comment: @nasch My point is that if you read a lat,lon pair of a visible feature off of Google Maps or Google Earth, you will not necessarily get what you'd get in the real world, because the georegistration of Google's imagery, though good, is inevitably not perfect.  See RomaH's answer.

Comment: Another quick point may be the rotation of the camera. If rotated on the X or Z axis (or the object holding the camera was, eg if the plane holding the camera hit some turbulence), then it would make objects appear 3D rather than just being taken straight down. Depending on the elevation of the object, this would put the object out of place.

Comment: @SteveSummit I was referring to the part where you said the physical monument itself may not correlate exactly with the boundary.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

There was a [discussion](https://surveyorconnect.com/community/gnss-geodesy/whats-the-most-youve-seen-ge-off/#post-578660) in a land surveying forum of how far off Google Earth was in various situations. Google Maps and Google Earth are not exactly the same product, but the discussion may be illuminating nevertheless. The amount of discrepancy noted by the OP seems in line with what the surveyors were finding.

To answer the question about which is correct, the [National Geodetic Survey explains it](https://www.ngs.noaa.gov/INFO/fourcorners.shtml). It is a fundamental principle that once a monument is erected on a boundary, the monument defines the boundary, even if the monuments are not exactly where the measurements described in legal instrument that directed their placement indicate. This would not apply if a monument were disturbed; since the monument has not been disturbed, the boundaries meet exactly where the monument is.

Comment: "It is a fundamental principal that once a boundary is monumented, the monuments define the boundary" This isn't always true. For instance, Stateline Road in Southaven, Mississippi is not actually on the state line between Tennessee and Mississippi.

Comment: "even if the monuments are not exactly where the measurements described in legal instrument that directed their placement indicate a different position." – It looks like you blended two different sentences there—like maybe you started with the intention of writing "even if the monuments are not exactly where the measurements … say they should be" but then finished the sentence as if it were "even if the measurements … indicate a different position."

Comment: @nick012000 Stateline Road is only a monument if all the relevant laws and legal documents say it is the monument that marks the state line. Often with state highways the state purchases and monuments with concrete posts an area to build the road. Then they can build the road anywhere between the lines of concrete posts. At the same time, sometimes a road is a monument; that is the case for my home.

Comment: @tanner Swett I accepted, with some slight punctuation changes, your suggested edit. Sometimes the boundary is established in writing first and then the monuments placed, which is what happened with the Four Corners Monument. Sometimes the monuments are placed first and then the legal instrument that creates the boundary is created. Either way the monuments control over the measurements, unless disturbed.

Comment: Re: "It is a fundamental principle that once a monument is erected on a boundary, the monument defines the boundary": It's a bit unfortunate to rely on this principle for answering this question, since the question mentions not just artificial or political boundaries (Four Corners, the prime meridian) but also natural geographic ones (the tropics, the equator).

Comment: @ruakh different kinds of lines and points on the earth that can be visited are subject to different kinds of uncertainty. As an example, the line of 0° longitude that passes near the Airy transit circle in the Royal Observatory, Greenwich, as of the end of the 19th century, passed through the transit circle by definition. But today the definition is much more abstract and the most practical way to find it within a few centimeters would be a survey-grade GNSS receiver.

Answer (score 23):

I am going to add a bit more background to Gerard Ashton's answer as my background is in mapping, surveying, and GIS. Gerard is absolutely correct. Whatever the original survey said is the location of the Four Corners is where the four corners is located. If the monument was placed there in accordance to the survey, the boundaries are located at that location.

But as to why Google Maps says otherwise...

The TLDR: The Earth is a bumpy, lumpy, slightly squashed sphere that is then flattened onto a map.  There are unavoidable distortions and errors.

*Yes... this is simplification, I am trying to fit at least two semesters of college classes into a few paragraphs for the lay person. There is probably a couple of errors, if they are egregious please comment.*

The difference between Google's location of the lines, the photographic location, and actual location is down to how the data is recorded, stored, and presented to you. It is common to use GPS coordinates (EPSG 4326) to store locations, but this makes a lot of assumptions about the actual surface you are standing on. This assumption of the surface is called an ellipsoid, an idealized surface of the planet and GPS uses an ellipsoid called WGS84. Because GPS services the entire world, it has to idealize the entire planet. But the planet is slightly squashed because of its rotation, the continents are slight raised because they are lighter than the magma they float on, in some areas the ground can raise as much as a metre after an earthquake. The Earth's shape isn't ideal, so there are going to errors between ideal and reality.

Most geographic data in the areas of the US acquired during or after the Louisiana Purchase are officially mapped in what is called Public Land Survey System, with much of modern work done in PLSS or State Plane. Within the State Plane system there are further subdivision depending on which area of which state you are surveying. For this coordinate system, it uses another idealized Earth, usually NAD27 or NAD83. This idealized Earth better fits the region, meaning measurements are more accurate. With surveyor gear, it is extremely accurate and used to define property rights. This is how the Four Corners area was defined and [why it is so straight](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/25197/9900).

So, Google maps is trying to take GPS coordinates, aerial photography, and various other spatial data, stored in various formats and coordinate systems and show them to you on a projection that is a derivative of a [map projection that was used for sailing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator_projection). *There is going to be error.* Because we don't have reference to the actual location using the surveyed coordinate system and projection, the photo and the lines shown by Google could all be incorrect. It is possible that nothing seen on that map could actually be in correct location. However, despite common thought, photography is usually done by airplane not satellite, and aerial photography is commonly taken by the local coordinate system. If I had placed a bet, I would say the photograph is more accurate, ignoring the fact it is stretched over a Mercator projection.

Using your phone's relatively bad GPS reciever, depending on number of satellites overhead, you can only expect 3-6 metre accuracy in the first place. Unless you spend [$10,000+ dollars on RTK GPS](https://www.agsgis.com/RTK-GPS-Explained_b_6.html), do some [post-processing](https://agriculture.mo.gov/weights/landsurvey/geodsrvy.php), or learn how to survey land, you probably are better relying on local knowledge. Consumer grade GPS is good for getting you close but not good for accuracy.

Comment: *NAD83*. PLSS, not state plane. State plane zones were defined well after these state boundaries were decided.

Comment: @mkennedy Yes, you are right, thanks.

Comment: IMO, your TL;DR explanation is incorrect or at least incomplete, since - as an unknowing observer - both the photographic textures as well as the visual/data boundaries could be assumed to undergo the same projection.

Comment: Additional source of error: the Earth's tectonic plates are constantly moving around, carrying border monuments with them.  This is why geographic datums need to be updated from time to time.

Comment: @phresnel I think the point is that the photos and data *originate* from different perspectives, which have already been affected by the lumps and bumps, so they need to be manipulated before they match *each other*.

Comment: RomaH wrote"Whatever the original survey said is the location of the Four Corners is where the four corners is located. If the monument was placed there in accordance to the survey, the boundaries are located at that location." Arguably, the monument IS the result of the survey, and it is meaningless to talk about the survey and the monument as two different things.

Answer (score 9):

The answer is somewhat interesting.  The monument itself is the legal border, as defined by New Mexico v. Colorado, 267 U.S. 30 (1925) because it lies directly on the lines "as surveyed".  However, the surveys themselves were slightly in error and may be as much as 1800 feet out from the geographical definition of the boundary referred to in the same court decision.

Refer: https://supreme.justia.com/cases/federal/us/267/30/, and https://web.archive.org/web/20111126151846/http://www.navajonationparks.org/pr/pr_4Cmarker.htm for a more detailed discussion.

Answer (score 7):

I don't know whether this is helpful, but below is a picture of my GPS (unfortunately without coordinates shown) from the middle of the monument at Four Corners. When I was there (in 2005) I recall somebody saying that "this is just representative, the actual border intersection is about a hundred yards over there in the desert". At the time I didn't attempt to go find it.

[image: GPS at Four Corners]

Comment: Your GPS (if it was showing) might not show the correct coordinates due to the world slowing down slightly. This is evidenced in various places using Greenwich observatory, which 'sort of' defines 0 longitude.  Also see: http://www.thegreenwichmeridian.org/tgm/articles.php?article=7 It can also lead into my favourite topic of all time - the difference between GMT and UTC.

Comment: @Jmons Isn't that rectified with leap seconds?

Comment: The point "a hundred yards over there in the desert" is the *intended* boundary point (about 540 feet northwest of the marker).  But as affirmed in *New Mexico v. Colorado*, the Four Corners monument is the location of the actual boundary point.

Comment: @GlenYates yes, but whilst we're waiting for a leap second it drifts, so you end up with it drifting uhh westwards, then leaping 100m (?) east with a leapsecond and then it drifts past the 'real' and back to the west (?)

Comment: Learning how modern latitude and longitude values are found, and how they are projected onto flat surfaces such as maps, could keep you busy while earning a degree in [geodetic engineering](https://ceg.osu.edu/faculty-research/research-overview/geodetic-engineering}. The short version is that leap seconds have nothing to do with the location of meridians of longitude or parallels of latitude.

Comment: @Jmons Definition of coordinates referenced to the mean sun is rather unusual, and using UTC for it even more so. WGS84 and all survey coordinates are referenced to points on the Earth, not the mean sun, and are not affected by the non-uniform rotation of Earth. And GPS does not use either GMT (UT1) or UTC anyway, it uses TAI - 19s.

Comment: Good catch @JanHudec